# Utf8 and overloaded strings in Haskell

Tags: haskell, utf-8, overloaded-strings

I realized that accents in my texts get converted to �.
I boiled it down, to the following example, which
writes (and overwrites) the file test.txt.

It uses exclusively methods from Data.Text, which are supposed
to handle unicode texts. I checked that both the source file 
as well the output file are encoded in utf8.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Prelude hiding (writeFile)
import Data.Text
import Data.Text.IO

someText :: Text
someText = "Université"

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    writeFile "test.txt" someText
```

After running the code, test.txt contains: Universit�.
In ghci, I get the following

```
*Main> someText
"Universit\233"
```

Is this already encoded incorrectly? I also found a comment on � in
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.2/docs/Data-Text.html,
but I still do not know how to correct the example above.

How do I use accents in an OverloadedString and correctly write them to a file?

Comment: Strings (and Text as well, I believe) in GHCi are printed after escaping "funny" chars: this is done as if the user typed `putStrLn (show string)` where `show` does the escaping and adds quotes. You can print the naked string/text by `putStrLn string` (remember to use `Data.Text.putStrLn` for text, instead of the prelude one)

Comment: putStrLn in ghci shows the accent correctly, so it must be writeFile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Data.Text`, and certainly not with `OverloadedStrings` – both handle UTF-8–Unicode just fine.

However `Data.Text.IO` will not write a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or anything that indicates the encoding, i.e. the file really just contains the text as-is. On any modern system, this means it will be in raw UTF-8 form:

```
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:~$ xxd test.txt 
00000000: 556e 6976 6572 7369 74c3 a9              Universit..
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:~$ cat test.txt 
Université
```

So depending on what editor you open the file with, it may guess a wrong encoding, and that's apparently your issue. On Linux, UTF-8 has long been the standard, so no issue here, but Windows isn't so up-to-date. It should be possible to manually select the encoding in any editor, though.

In fact, `Data.Text.IO.writeFile` will use your [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)) to decide how to encode the file. [Everybody should have UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/) as their locale nowadays, if you don't please change that.

To get a BOM in your file and thus preclude such issues, use [`utf8_bom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:utf8_bom).

Regarding the output you see in GHCi: that's the `Show` instance at work; it escapes any string-like values to the safest conceivable form, i.e. anything that's not ASCII to an escape sequence, which for `'é'` happens to be `'\233'`. Again not specific to `Text`, in fact you get this even for single characters:

```
Prelude> 'é'
'\233'
Prelude> putChar '\233'
é
```

This escaping never happens when you use the direct-IO-output actions for your string types, i.e. `putChar`, `putStr` or `putStrLn`.

```
Prelude> import qualified Data.Text.IO as Txt
Prelude Txt> Txt.putStrLn "Université"
Université
```

Comment: I opened test.txt in an editor and set the encoding manually to utf8. Still I do not get the accent. How can I tell what encoding writeFile uses?

Comment: I thought it was always UTF-8, but [as per the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.2/docs/Data-Text-IO.html#g:2) it actually uses your locale to decide. I strongly recommend you set your locale to UTF-8 and never need to worry about it again. Alternatively you can of course create a bytestring in any encoding you like (just, nowadays [you should _never_ use anything but UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/), so...).

Comment: Indeed, my locale for my stack haskell installation is not set to utf8. I have no idea how to change that, but one can use "setLocaleEncoding utf8" to change it in the code.